# Script throwing an error after starting the service

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting

I have written the below code to `start` the `service`:

```
invoke-command -cn $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
param($svc) 
if((get-service $svc).status -ne "running") {
    get-service $svc| start-service     
    set-service $svc -StartupType Automatic
    (get-service $svc).waitforstatus('running')  
 }
 get-service $svc| select ServiceName
} -ArgumentList $svc
```

After executing the above script, I am getting below error:

```
Status         : Running
StartType      : Automatic
ServiceName    : svcname
PSComputerName : host1

+     invoke-command -cn $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

**I see service is `Running` successfully so why it is throwing an error even when the service was started correctly?**

I am using `poweshell 5`

Comment: `StartServiceFailed` would indicate that it's not _after_ starting the service, it's `Start-Service` itself that's failing. Check the System event log on the target machine

Comment: how to check system event log on a remove machine? what cmdlet to use?

Comment: You cannot use `$host` as self-defined variable because it is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#host): _Contains an object that represents the current host application for PowerShell._ Choose a different name for that

Comment: @Theo thanks for pointing it out. already made that change and also updated my question

Comment: Great, but is this a typo also? `set-service $svc-StartupType`.. There should be a space between $svc and parameter `-StartyupType` I also believe you need to set the startup type **before** starting it and you could do with a lot less calls to `get-service`. Why not store it in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comments, try:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    param($svc) 
    $theService = Get-Service -Name $svc
    if($theService.Status -ne 'Running') {
        if ($theService.Status -ne 'Stopped') { $theService | Stop-Service -Force }
        $theService | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic
        ($theService | Start-Service -PassThru).WaitForStatus('Running')
     }
     $theService | Select-Object ServiceName
} -ArgumentList $svc
```

Comment: thanks this is miraculously working fine without any error!

Comment: @meallhour Thanks, sorry for the very short description, but I was pressed for time..

Comment: I see the script is failing again on one server. the only difference is that it is in `Paused` state right now. `Status         : Paused`
`StartType      : Automatic`  `+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError:` `(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],ServiceCommandException`

Comment: @meallhour Hmm.. Looks like we have to do a waiting loop to make sure it has stopped after `Stop-Service`. I'm on mobile now but will edit tomorrow

Comment: sure. I am trying to manually start the service, it is throwing an error saying that the service and the service is stuck in `paused state.`

Comment: @meallhour Wow... Sounds like a bigger problem there. Can you restart the machine?

Comment: one service dependency was missing so it was not related to the script. it is working fine now.

Comment: @meallhour Ah, good to hear!